# Form submission Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm getting this error message while submitting the form:

```
Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("abcd.com", "test", "test", "test");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO survey1 (location, age, gender, marital, q1, q1_1, q1_2, q1_3, q1_4, q2, q3, q4, q5, q5_1, q5_2, q5_3, q5_4, q6, q7, q8, q8_others, q9, q9_others, q10, q11, q12, q12_1, q12_2, q12_3, q12_4, q13, q14, q15, q16, q17, q17_others, q18, q19, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24, q25, q25_others, q26, q27, q28, q29, q30, q31, q32, q32_1, q32_2, q32_3, q32_4, q33, q34, q34_others) VALUES('$_POST[location]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[marital]', '$_POST[q1]', '$_POST[q1_1]', '$_POST[q1_2]', '$_POST[q1_3]', '$_POST[q1_4]', '$_POST[q2]', '$_POST[q3]', '$_POST[q4]', '$_POST[q5]', '$_POST[q5_1]', '$_POST[q5_2]', '$_POST[q5_3]', '$_POST[q5_4]', '$_POST[q6]', '$_POST[q7]', '$_POST[q8]', '$_POST[q8_others]', '$_POST[q9]', '$_POST[q9_others]', '$_POST[q10]', '$_POST[q11]', '$_POST[q12]', '$_POST[q12_1]', '$_POST[q12_2]', '$_POST[q12_3]', '$_POST[q12_4]', '$_POST[q13]', '$_POST[q14]', '$_POST[q15]', '$_POST[q16]', '$_POST[q17]', '$_POST[q18]', '$_POST[q19]', '$_POST[q20]', '$_POST[q21]', '$_POST[q22]', '$_POST[q23]', '$_POST[q24]', '$_POST[q25]', '$_POST[q25_others]', '$_POST[q26]', '$_POST[q27]', '$_POST[q28]', '$_POST[q29]', '$_POST[q30]', '$_POST[q31]', '$_POST[q32]', '$_POST[q32_1]', '$_POST[q32_2]', '$_POST[q32_3]', '$_POST[q32_4]', '$_POST[q33]', '$_POST[q34]', '$_POST[q34_others]')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    header("Location: thankyou.html");
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is self explanatory - you are trying to set X columns by providing Y values, but the X must equal Y. In other works if you try to set 3 columns by providing 2 values, you will get that error. Check passed arguments and add missing one

If you are using MySQL then I suggest using different syntax, which is less error prone:

```
 INSERT INTO table SET column=value, column2=value2, ...;
```

BTW: you are asking for troubles not escaping your values. NEVER pass user provided content directly to your query - always escape using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or similar methods. Or use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use a PHP Framework or MySQLi Class that contains functions making your workflow faster and mainly easier.

If you look for a PHP Framework take your time and choose according to your requirements (e.g. the size of your project / app) and your programming knowledge.

A good entry would be [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) as it is easy to understand (dive into the source) has a low learning curve and a thorough documentation.

For a MySQLi Class I can recommend https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class .

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `q17_others` column that isn't include in the set of values that you are inserting.

A sample of your columns looks like this:

```
... q16, q17, q17_others, q18,  ...
```

And the same section from your values:

```
... '$_POST[q16]', '$_POST[q17]', '$_POST[q18]', ...
```

Also, I would agree with everything Marcin Orlowski said in his answer. This is not a safe way to insert data into your database. At the very least you should be escaping the input, but it would be preferable to use something like PDO and with bindParam calls.